# content div is not fixed

Tags: html, css, responsive

The content div is not responsive..

It's covering the header and footer as the width and height of browser shrinks..

I'm using flex too (not sure if I'm using it properly though)

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

Maybe I'm using it wrong..

I'm using content as an overlay on a background video too..

Am I overriding something?
Please help!!

Here's the Jsfiddle example- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgufeu7r/)

Here's the code snippet-

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
}

header a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  width: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.quote {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 3rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<video poster=".jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
        pro.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
        pro.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
        pro.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="quote">get a quote!</div>
    <footer>copyright 2018</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also..if possible I want a lil arrow under the menus..to show user which page s/he is currently on..

But it's not fixed(again)

Here's the css code I'm using:

```
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -9px;
  content: ' ';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: why are you using `position: fixed;` on everything? Your layout is not that responsive friendly

Comment: I know..I tried "absolute" then I was checking if fixed would work or not :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the responsive website then you can use bootstrap. Using bootstrap its easy for you to make responsive layout for your website.
Try this below code if its help you out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;

  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  clear:both;
}

header a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  width: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.quote {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 3rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<video poster=".jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="container-fluid">
  <div >

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>


    <div class='col-sm-12'>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
        pro.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
        pro.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
        pro.
      </p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quote">get a quote!</div>
    <footer>copyright 2018</footer>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes..it helps to make it responsive but I can't able to change menus background to transparent.. Also I wanted header to not stick to the top..I wanted a lil margin from top..

Comment: Is there other way to do it without using bootstrap?